# How to use a txt file to build a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use a txt file that contains the dictionary to transform the aa from 3 letters alphabet to 1 letter alphabet, I have to open this file as dictionary in my Python script but I can't, it returns me an error:

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
this is my code:

```
with open ('test.txt') as file:
for line in file:
 line.replace('\n','').split()
  return dic(file)
```

This is my txt file:

```
AA_code = dict( [ ["ALA", "A"], ["ARG", "R"], ["ASP", "D"], ["THR", "T"], ["PRO", "P"], ["HIS", "H"], ["SER", "S"], ["TRP", "W"], ["GLY", "G"], ["PHE", "F"], ["GLU", "E"], ["CYS", "C"], ["TYR", "Y"], ["VAL", "V"], ["LYS", "K"], ["GLN", "Q"], ["ASN", "N"], ["LEU", "L"], ["MET", "M"], ["ILE", "I"], ] )
```

Comment: Can you also include an example of the data? It sounds like the first couple of lines would do it.

Comment: The "txt file" already looks like Python. Is this correct? Seems like an antipattern to be trying to parse this as raw text--just make it a module and import it as code.

Answer (score 0):

***If*** you trust the source of the text file, you could do something like this since it's contents appears to be Python code:

```
def get_aa_codes(filename):
    gbls = {'__builtins__': {'dict': dict}}

    with open(filename) as file:
        exec(file.read(), gbls)

    return gbls['AA_code']


print(get_aa_codes('dict_test.txt'))
```

Printed results:

```
{'ALA': 'A', 'ARG': 'R', 'ASP': 'D', 'THR': 'T', 'PRO': 'P', 'HIS': 'H', 'SER': 'S', 'TRP': 'W', 'GLY': 'G', 'PHE': 'F', 'GLU': 'E', 'CYS': 'C', 'TYR': 'Y', 'VAL': 'V', 'LYS': 'K', 'GLN': 'Q', 'ASN': 'N', 'LEU': 'L', 'MET': 'M', 'ILE': 'I'}
```